# IF condition update values depending out or inside interval

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to check if there is a more efficient (o neat) to express the next condition:

- I want to check if the value of the parameter 'a' is inside the interval. If it is in the interval, a remains the same, but...
- if it is lower or higher than the minimum or maximum value of the interval, the parameter 'a' should be updated with the minimum or maximum values depending on the case. This code works perfectly fine:

> ```
> a=1000
> if 0<=a<=800:
>     a=a
> elif a>800:
>     a=800
> else:
>     a=0
> print('a is',a)
> ```

I have to repeat this kind of condition for a relatively large set of different parameters, so I was wondering if I can do this in a more efficient/neat way.

Comment: a = max(min(a,800),0)  is an alternative, which is neater.  but it is not more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
a = max(min(high, a), low)
```

and for reusability, we can wrap it in a function:

```
def clip(param, low, high):
    return max(min(high, param), low)
```

This first compares `a` with `high` and takes the minimum (so if `a > high`, we're left with `high`) then the result is compared with `low` with `min` (so that we guarantee to be at least `low`).

Sample runs:

```
>>> clip(1000, low=0, high=800)
800

>>> clip(1000, low=1200, high=3800)
1200

>>> clip(3, low=0, high=10)
3
```

---

An alternative is (perhaps unreadable) ternaries:

```
a = high if a > high else (low if a < low else a)
```

This also can be put in a function in the same manner.

Comment: I think `lambda` function would have been more appropriate, just personal preference.

Comment: @ThePyGuy I see; named lambda's are discouraged by PEP 8 i guess but as you said, it's personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

Two simple ifs:

```
def bound(v, min_,max_):
   if v < min_:
      v = min_
   if v > max_
      v = max_  
   return v
```

With min/max:

```
def bound(v,min_,max_):
    return max(min(v,max_),min_v)
```

I think the first version is going to be faster in practice.